# How to replicate final crop parameters in after Ken Burns effect

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I'm using a Ken Burns effect to zoom in on a section of running video.  After the zoom completes I want the next section of video to continue with the same crop dimensions.  How do I find out the exact dimensions that the Ken Burns effect finishes with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Ken-Burns-type crop to create the effect, I did it using Transform effects, setting a Keyframe at the beginning and the end of the zoom.  I think the relative rates of zoom and pan may be a little different with this method, but it works for my purposes.  It should be possible to tweak the settings to create a steady zoom/pan.

So now I can just click on the final keyframe in the Transform row of the Video Animation display for that section of video to get the final X, Y, and Scale values.